# Estimating the integral of $\frac{x^s}{s}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I am trying to understand a proof in number theory but I do not understand the part where we estimate an integral as follows. The assumption is $0<x<1$. I appreciate any idea of how to prove this estimate.

[image: the estimate of the integral]

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{U-iR}^{U+iR}\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-iR}^{iR}\frac{x^U x^t}{U+t}\,dt=\frac{x^U}{2\pi i}\int_{-iR}^{+iR}\frac{\exp(t\log x)}{U+t}\,dt=\frac{x^U}{2\pi }\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\exp(i\sigma\log x)}{U+i\sigma}\,d\sigma $$
equals
$$ \frac{x^U}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{\cos(\sigma\log x)+i\sin(\sigma\log x)}{U+i\sigma}+\frac{\cos(\sigma\log x)-i\sin(\sigma\log x)}{U-i\sigma}\,d\sigma $$
or
$$ \frac{x^U}{\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{U}{U^2+\sigma^2}\cos(\sigma\log x)+\frac{\sigma}{U^2+\sigma^2}\sin(\sigma\log x)\,d\sigma. $$

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz the last integrand function is bounded in absolute value by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{U^2+\sigma^2}}\leq\frac{1}{U}$, hence
$$ \left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{U-iR}^{U+iR}\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds\right|\leq \frac{x^U R}{\pi U}. $$

Comment: You can also use $\vert \int_I f(s) ds \vert \le \max | f(s)| \vert I \vert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bound

$$\left \vert \int_I f(s) ds \right\vert \le \max_{s\in I} | f(s)| \vert I \vert.$$

In our case

$$
\max_{s\in I} | f(s)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{\max_{s\in I} | x^s|}{\min_{s\in I} | s|} = \frac{x^U}{2 \pi U}, 
$$
and $\vert I \vert = 2 R$ completes the proof.